# ArrayExceptionOut Of Bound

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-asynctask

**Updated Question from previous:** I filled an array through HashMap, Iam using Asynctask for http request & after filling array put that array in dialog box. When I first run my app it gives me an empty dialog box & didn't give any error but when I re run my app it shows all array elements in dialog box perfectly. Whats the reason ?

```
//JsonResponse Inner Class in main class

private class JsonResponse extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    String response = "";
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> prServices_resultList =
        new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {   
        if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("Success"))
        {
             ResultList_List = prServices_resultList;    
             int s=0;
             for (HashMap<String, String> hashServices : prServices_resultList)
             {
                 Db_Services[s] = hashServices.get(android_S_CName);                
                 Db_ServicesID[s] = hashServices.get(android_S_ID);
                 s++;
             }
        }
    }

    protected String doInBackground(final String... args)
    {    
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONArray jArrayServices = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url_Services);

        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < jArrayServices.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject jsonElements = jArrayServices.getJSONObject(i);

                String S_id = jsonElements.getString(android_S_ID);
                String S_name = jsonElements.getString(android_S_NAME);

                HashMap<String, String> hashServices = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key
                hashServices.put(android_S_ID, S_id);
                hashServices.put(android_S_NAME, S_name);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                prServices_resultList.add(hashServices);
            }
            response = "Success";
        }
        catch(JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

In my main class have have a button & when i press i execute AsyncTask:

```
new JsonResponse().execute;
```

In main class above onCreate i declare like:

```
static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ResultList_Services = 
    new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

String[] Db_Services = new String[ResultList_Services.size()];
String[] Db_ServicesID = new String[ResultList_Services.size()];
```

Comment: Can you point to the exact line where the exception is being thrown?

Comment: Are you sure that in first run you waited AsyncTask to finish its job? It may be that in second run, data are ready.

Comment: @J.Romero issue is my arrays are at the top of main activity & equal to arraylist.size.. i want to use these arrays in Asynctask to get filled from http response.. the reason i put them in main activity is because i want to use them in other methods of main activity..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an empty map here:

```
ResultList_Services = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

Then trying to initialize two arrays with the size of an empty map -  being zero.

```
// ResultList_Services.size() will be zero
String[] Db_Services  =  new String[ResultList_Services.size()]; 
String[] Db_ServicesID  =  new String[ResultList_Services.size()];
```

So when you try adding to these arrays it will throw an `OutOfBoundsException`

---

You could make these Arrays into lists, then you can dynamically add elements as needed without needing to specify a size to start with. If you then need an Array (for other Methods) you can get an array from a list using [`List#toArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28%29)

---

**As per your comment**

You could just create temporary arrays to which you add all the elements and then assign this to your other arrays, something like

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
{   
    if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("Success"))
    {
         ResultList_List = prServices_resultList;    
         String[] tmp_dbServ = new String[prServices_resultList.size()];
         String[] tmp_dbServID = new String[prServices_resultList.size()];
         int s=0;
         for (HashMap<String, String> hashServices : prServices_resultList)
         {
             tmp_dbServ[s] = hashServices.get(android_S_CName);                
             tmp_dbServID[s] = hashServices.get(android_S_ID);
             s++;
         }
         Db_Services = tmp_dbServ;
         Db_ServicesID = tmp_dbServID;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Java Devil what i want is to fill these arrays after asynctask is finish, the reason i put arrays in the start of activity is because i want to use them in main activity other methods.. i knew they are getting zero. i have a button i want to start asynctask when i press it and then fill these arrays, any solution

Comment: @AndroidLover Use lists with dynamic sizing as opposed to arrays with a fixed size. You can always get an array from a list if needed.

Comment: @JavaDevil is their any way that i fill array inside asynctask & onPost i make them equal to another array of main activity class as i did for my ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>.. plz guide me